# how to implement interface with variable key and define key at the sametime

Tags: typescript

I want to create an interface with a defined key, and also a variable key, like so :

```
interface Data {
  api?: {
    isReady: boolean;
  };
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

Which leads to an error : `Property 'api' of type '{ isReady: boolean; }' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.`

I understand that `[key:string]: string` says "every key of this interface should have a string as its value", which is not the case for `api`, so the error makes sense.

So, is this possible to create such an interface, with a clearly define key/value pair + a variable key at the same level?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you maybe want to to create an object that looks like this:

```
 interface Data {
  api?: {
    isReady: boolean;
  };
  [key: string]: any;
}

const data: Data = { 'api': { isReady: false }, 'someText': 'text' };
console.log(data);
```

[image]

Although it looks like a good idea doing so, it may not be the case because in this way you loose Type-safety.

Answer (score 1):

The `api` property might have its own type:

```js
interface Api {
  isReady: boolean;
};
```

Then, we can mix the typings for the variable part:

```js
interface Data {
  api?: Api;
  [key: string]: string | Api;
}
```

Comment: It kind of works, altough I'm not really satisfied because the [key: string] value should not have the `isReady` property. :/

Comment: this is more of a conceptual mistake i'm doing right there, I should find an other solution

Comment: are you familiar with typescript utility types? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#introduction